# PHP development environment with docker (and how to use composer)

Tags: php, composer-php, docker

I play with docker for a while and I wanted to use this to build a PHP development environment.
With PHP I use composer.

Despite my research about using docker to build a devlopmenet environment, I essentially found sample code showing how to run an existing PHP app (but not how to make a development environment)
like : https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-php

I don't really understand if I have to run composer inside the container or outside ?

Can you show me some examples where I have my source code in a directory on the host, shared with container via a docker volume and how to use composer with this setup ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

interesting setup here :
geoffrey.io/a-php-development-environment-with-docker.html

available on github :
https://github.com/ubermuda/docker-symfony